# On the meaning of "θάνατός ἐστιν ὁκόσα ἐγερθέντες ὁρέομεν, ὁκόσα δὲ εὕδοντες ὕπνος"

Tags: presocratics

Can someone give an explation on the meaning of "θάνατός ἐστιν ὁκόσα ἐγερθέντες ὁρέομεν, ὁκόσα δὲ εὕδοντες ὕπνος," a remaining fragment by Heraclitus.

[This](http://www.heraclitusfragments.com/files/ge.html) website translated it as "All the things we see when awake are death, even as all we see in slumber are sleep".

Comment: Google translate gives: "death of the eldest we raised, we drove eighteen times". Whenever I use Google translate I'm far less worried about the AI apocalypse.

Comment: You can try Latin SE, they handle Greek as well if someone happens to be there who knows it.

Answer (score 2):

B21: 'Death is all things we see awake; all we see asleep is sleep (thanatos estin hokosa egerthentes horeomen, hokosa de ehudontes hupnos). ('B21' - numeration from 6th edition of Diels-Kranz, Fragmente der Vorsokratiker (1951).

No easy fragment to elucidate:

## Background

> In sleep men make up a world of their own, a world of dreams. "A man
>    strikes a light for himself in the night, when his sight is quenched" (B26),
>    just as most men make up a world of their own when they "conjecture for
>    themselves" and "do not think things in the way they encounter them" (B 17).
>    Heraclitus, unlike most in antiquity, does not credit dreams or sleep with the
>    possibility of yielding anything of positive epistemic value. Homer credits
>    those dreams that come by way of the "gate of horn," as opposed to those
>    that come by way of the "gate of ivory," with truth (Od. 19.560-67), and
>    the gods may send messages, some truthful (Od. 4.795-837), some deceptive (II. 2.5-6), to humans through their dreams. The souls of the dead may
>    visit the living in their sleep and communicate with them. The soul of the
>    dead Patroclus visits Achilles in his sleep and urges him to bury his body
>    as quickly as possible so that his soul may enter the realm of the dead
>    (H. 23.65-98, cf. Pind. Pyth. 4.159-63). Pindar even believes that sleep pro-
>    vides a superior epistemic condition."I The soul, *aionos*, *eidolon*, which is
>    of a divine nature, is inactive, asleep, when a man is awake; it becomes active during his sleep, and "in many dreams it reveals an approaching decision of things pleasant or distressful" (frag. 131b). For Heraclitus, "all we
>    see asleep is sleep" (B21). (Herbert Granger, 'Death's Other Kingdom: Heraclitus on the Life of the Foolish and the Wise', Classical Philology, Vol. 95, No. 3 (Jul., 2000), pp. 260-281: 264.)

## Main text

> B21 opens cryptically with, "Death is all things we see awake," and, as
>    Kahn argues, this clause plausibly comments upon the constant state of
>    change within nature, in which bodies emerge from the perishing of other
>    bodies, that the "birth" of one element is the "death" of another (B36). On
>    this interpretation Heraclitus might just as well have said that "life" is all
>    we see awake. He might, however, readily agree with this because of his
>    drawing together of opposites into some sort of unity, in particular, life and
>    death (B88, B48, B15); and his focus on "death" may reflect his predilection for stressing the negative of any opposing pair (B80, B53). However
>    this may be, **B21 corroborates the cognitive worthlessness of sleep. All "we
>    see" awake is death, but, if we turn to sleep, no epistemic advantage seems
>    to be gained, in disagreement with Pindar (frag. 131b), since "all we see
>    asleep is sleep."** Yet since B26 ties sleep and death together ['A man
>    strikes a light for himself in the night, when his sight is quenched'], this fragment
>    may, in turn, comment on B21. If sleep is "contact," whatever that may
>    mean exactly, with the dead, then the two clauses of B21 are more balanced  than might at first be presumed,44 since they both concern death in some
>    respect. Awake "we see" only death; asleep all we see is sleep, but as B26
>    indicates in sleep we are in "contact" with the dead. Then, just as in our
>    waking state, we also have to do with the dead in our sleep. In addition,
>    *hapthesnai* could even mean "perceive," at least in the time of Sophocles, so
>    that B26 might be read to mean that in sleep humans "perceive" the dead.
>    In the light of this reading of B26, B21 would mean no matter where we
>    turn, in waking or in sleeping, we "perceive," or perhaps "experience," death
>    in some form or another. The grammatical construction of B21 bears out the
>    connection between death and sleep. Its first word is *thanatos*; and its last
>    *hupnos*;, and their positions at the extremes of the sentence Heraclitus may
>    intend as a comment upon their nature. Just as in B90 the location of "fire"
>    at the beginning and "gold" at the end of the sentence are surely intended to
>    reflect the parallel between fire and gold Heraclitus develops in B90, since
>    if the sentence is thought to form a ring, it would end where it began.
>
> But on this reading of B21, after the fashion of the ring construction of
>    B90, "sleep" should be death, or a state much like death, and the "contact"
>    the living in their sleep have with the dead in B26 should amount to a
>    version of death. *hapthestai* can contribute to this interpretation also, where
>    ''contact,'' in the sense of "come up to" or "reach," may mean something
>    like "match." This seems to be how Freeman reads *haptetai* in the second
>    clause when she translates it as, "while living, he approximates to a dead
>    man during sleep": the sleeper, although alive, is like the dead. The third
>    clause of B26 reads on Freeman's rendering, "while awake, he approximates
>    to one who sleeps." The state of the common man in his ignorance amounts
>    in his waking life to sleep (B 1, B 89), but Heraclitus likely has more in mind
>    than this. As others have observed, the second and third clauses form a
>    proportional statement, as waking is to sleeping, sleeping is to death. On the
>    view that *haptetai* means something like "resemble," sleep would be the
>    term, on the basis of the proportion, that draws together waking life and
>    death. The opposites of life and death are somehow the "same," as Heraclitus makes explicit in B88, and, for that matter, so too are waking and sleeping the "same": "the same things in us, living and dead and the waking and
>    sleeping and young and old." As waking life resembles sleep, sleep resembles death; thus life resembles death, so much so, perhaps Heraclitus thinks,
>    that he is willing to say that life and death are the "same." (Herbert Granger, 'Death's Other Kingdom: Heraclitus on the Life of the Foolish and the Wise', Classical Philology, Vol. 95, No. 3 (Jul., 2000), pp. 260-281: 273-4.)